# Embed Google "my map" on Google Site but No Maps Found

Tags: google-maps, google-sites

I am trying to embed a "My Map" on a Google Site (sites.google.com). I am following this documentation:

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/154195?hl=en

but at step 4 in embedding a custom map, I see a message that says "No maps found". The result is the same if my map security is Public on the map, or anyone with the link. Any suggestions on how to embed my custom map on a google site?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. Your map has to be set to public then on your map description (top right) click on the folder icon next to "Add Layer" and choose "Embed on my site". Copy the html. Open your site and click the HTML button while in edit mode. Paste the HTML and the map will show up. If anyone has an answer to why the maps don't show up in the my maps tab, I would still like to know.